# React with Bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using React with Bootstrap 4, and have a modal with a form which I would like to dismiss on a successful submit. The documentation [suggests there is a "dispose" method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaldispose). I'm trying to implement it in the form's action, like this:

```
const plotModal = document.getElementById('plotModal');
plotModal.modal('dispose');
```

This doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try $('#plotModal').modal('dispose');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try close function

```
plotModal.modal('hide')
```

Comment: That doesn't workright-but $('#plotModal').modal('hide'); does. What's the vanilla JS equivalent?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap with React. I don't recommend to use pure bootstrap library with react.js directly. There are projects which port bootstrap components to react components so that you can use vanilla javascript to manipulate components without jQuery.
Example project: https://reactstrap.github.io/